# Can We download HTMLs from the mockup's URL hosted in Axshare?

Tags: url, mockups

Can We download HTMLs from the mockup's URL hosted in Axshare? Without Login can we download complete mockups and store it locally?

Answer (score 0):

No you cant download without login